# How to speed up the react output of Audio app

Tags: android, reactjs, performance, cordova, audio

I did create a React Cordova app that listen the mic based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API, and shows a visualization of the listening mic sound.
I can see a delay of about 1 second or maybe more, between the sound which is output in the speakers in my room and the graph shown on the Android app.
I can imagine a few possible reasons:

- 1. React is not fast enough for such an app, which I doubt
- 2. I am analyzing too many frequencies of the audio data, and somehow I should only get frequencies I am interested in...
- 3. My phone is too slow.

Do you have any suggestions to improve the output of this specific app?

Answer (score 0):

Have a skim through this article and see if you can avoid the listed sources of performance problems. When debugging you can also use the console.log function to record when a method has finished running (using the Date class to get the current time) to compare and see what methods are being cumbersome.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance

If you are still having trouble be sure to share some code snippets that may be causing issues for the lovely Stack Overflow community to have a look at and maybe someone will find something :)